# LaTeXのfigure環境で位置指定をtbからHに変更するとエラーになる

Tags: latex

`\usepackage{float}`を加えても何事もないのですが、なぜか`\begin{figure}[tb]`を`\begin{figure}[H]`に書き換えた途端、以下のようなエラーが出ます。改善する方法を教えていただけないでしょうか？

エラー

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
 \end{figure}
! Emergency stop.
<inserted text> 
                }
 \end{figure}
```

コード

```
\documentclass{his}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig} \let\epsfile=\epsfig
\usepackage{float}

%和文タイトル  論文のヘッダ部分にも出力されます．
\jtitle{}

%著者日本名
\jauthor{
\thanks{}　 
}

%英文タイトル
\etitle{}

%著者英文名
\eauthor{
\thanks{}
}

%投稿時には \YEAR{2002} \VOL{0} \NO{0} としてください．
\YEAR{2002}
\VOL{0}       
\NO{0}

%原稿の種別により以下のうち，１つの「%」をはずしてください．
\TYPE{原著論文}
%\TYPE{総説論文}
%\TYPE{技術報告}
%\TYPE{ショートノート}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     英語の種別では{\small }を使う
%
%
%\TYPE{Original Paper}
%\TYPE{Review Paper}
%\TYPE{Techinical Report}
%\TYPE{Short Note}

%原稿受付日，再受付日
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     日本語の場合
%             年，月，日
%
%投稿時には \received{2002}{1}{1} としてください．
\received{2002}{1}{1}
\revised{2002}{1}{1}
%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     英語の場合
%             月（英語）日，年の表示に
%
%投稿時には \received{2002}{Jan.}{1} としてください．
%\received{2002}{Jan.}{1}
%\revised{2002}{Jan.}{1}
%


\begin{document}

%maketitle は abstract と keyword の後に入れてください．

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}       

\end{keyword}

\maketitle    

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{はじめに}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{研究概要}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\subsection{対象}

\subsection{方法}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{システム}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\subsection{システム概要}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{図・表}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}[H]
      \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[width=70mm]{Level.png}
      \caption{難易度選択}       
      \label{formula}
      \end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[tb]
      \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[width=70mm]{Menu.png}
      \caption{メニュー選択}       
      \label{formula}
      \end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[tb]
      \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[width=70mm]{MetaQuest3.jpg}
      \caption{Meta Quest3}       
      \label{formula}
      \end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[tb]
      \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[width=70mm]{kinect_s.jpg}
      \caption{Microsoft Kinect}       
      \label{formula}
      \end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[tb]
      \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[width=70mm]{System.png}
      \caption{Input Output}       
      \label{formula}
      \end{center}
\end{figure}


\section{関連研究}


\section{課題}

\section{参考文献}


\end{document}
```

Comment: 示されたコードがfigure環境の中身だけだと原因の特定は難しそうです。現在の文書ソースの全部でなくてもよいので、無関係の部分を削って「単独でコンパイル可能なソースコード全体」かつ「同じエラーが発生する」コード（Minimal Working Example; MWE）を示してもらえますか？

Comment: すいません。書きました。

Comment: 再現しました。ヒューマンインターフェース学会のhisクラスの代わりにjsarticleを用いると同問題は発生しませんね。hisの中身を見るとfigure環境を上書きしていそうです。率直に言うと「hisクラスではfloatパッケージの利用はサポートされていない」ということになるかと思います。

Comment: floatパッケージは使わず、標準の`h`指定子で間に合わないでしょうか？